# Como alterar as cores de barras individualmente em matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Olá! Será que alguém consegue me explicar como funciona o princípio para se alterar as cores das barras individualmente? Só consigo alterar a cor do gráfico todo.

Por exemplo: De Azul para preto / De laranja para cinza / De verde para vermelho

Se puderem me ajudar, serei muito grato. Att,

```
df3 = df_interest.iloc[[0,1,2,3,4],:3]

df3.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20,8), width=0.8)
plt.title("Percentage of Respondents' Interest in Data Science Areas")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é so passar o parâmetro `color` para a função `.plot()`, com uma lista dos valores RGB das cores? Algo como `color = ['#000000','#AAAAAA','#FF0000']`.

Comment: Isso mesmo! Muito obrigado! RESOLVIDO!